# While Loop Update TextView

Tags: android, loops, android-studio

I have a code here

```
File file = new File(FilePathname_CUS);
CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader();
try (CsvParser csvParser = csvReader.parse(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    CsvRow row;
    if (count_row(FilePathname_SAMPLE) != 0) {
        myDb.delete_customer(current_email);
        int index = 0;
        while ((row = csvParser.nextRow()) != null) {
            myDb.insert_customer(
                    row.getField(0),
                    row.getField(1),
                    row.getField(2),
                    row.getField(3),
                    row.getField(4),
                    row.getField(5),
                    row.getField(6),
                    row.getField(7),
                    row.getField(8),
                    row.getField(9)
            );

            index++;
            float p = (float)index / (float)row_count;
            p = p * (float)100;
            //mProgressAnimation.setProgress((int)p);
            counter_load.setText((int)p);
        }
    }
}
```

for every loop i saved the data in database but my target is to update the textview based on current percentage but what happens is that the textview only changes after while loop how can i update it during the loop?

Comment: Is this loop running on the main Thread?

Comment: you mean while an activity is shown? yes

Comment: post all your code about your question

Comment: thats all the code i got. i mean other code is not connected with this one

Comment: No, I mean, are you running that inside another Thread? Is it being run asynchronously?

Comment: As I am seeing in your code, you are updating the text into the loop, what is the result that you got?

Comment: @BrankVictoria it only updates after loop

Comment: Probably, you are seeing 100% because the loop goes too fast? Will you try to put  a Thread.Sleep(100) after update the text so you can see if it is really updating.

Comment: @TheWanderer this is my first time doing this all my code where run onCreate method and as far as i know im not using another thread. Same activity

Comment: @myownemail it seems that it is with lower-case and you also will need the library `import java.lang.*;`  `Thread.sleep(1000);`

Comment: @BrankVictoria sround with try and catch?

Comment: Yes, you need to surround that line by try and catch because that function can throw an exception

Comment: @BrankVictoria nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

by using new Thread and Handler.
try this code :

```
File file = new File(FilePathname_CUS);
    CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader();
    try (CsvParser csvParser = csvReader.parse(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {

        if (count_row(FilePathname_SAMPLE) != 0) {
            myDb.delete_customer(current_email);

     Thread thread;
     final Handler handler = new Handler();
     thread =  new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int index = 0;
            CsvRow row;
            while ((row = csvParser.nextRow()) != null) {
                myDb.insert_customer(
                        row.getField(0),
                        row.getField(1),
                        row.getField(2),
                        row.getField(3),
                        row.getField(4),
                        row.getField(5),
                        row.getField(6),
                        row.getField(7),
                        row.getField(8),
                        row.getField(9)
                );

                index++;
                float p = (float)index / (float)row_count;
                p = p * (float)100;


                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                         counter_load.setText((int)p);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    // Sleep for 100 milliseconds.
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    });
    thread.start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: this one gave me an error on my past created variables

Comment: it has an `Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException` error on `nextRow()` on `while`

Comment: on this part it has an error `while ((row = csvParser.nextRow()) != null) {` and that is `Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException`